# which Visual C++ Redistributable package should I be using with py2exe?

Tags: python, py2exe

I have a `wxPython` **GUI** that I am compiling into an executable using `py2exe`.  Based on this [tutorial](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial#Step5).

I believe that I need to provide *Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable* to make my program run on the user's machine.

I'm just wondering if the **2008 version** is really the one I should be using.  I'm running `py2exe` on `Windows 10`.

Should I be using a more up to date version?  My project is **pure** Python, so I did not directly use Visual Studio at any point.

Comment: wxPython is inherently not pure python, you would not be able to make a library like that using only Python, which is probably why it requires VC++ '08.

Comment: It's not clear that you can legally redistribute the Visual C++ runtime. That right is given to licensed users of Visual Studio so that they can redistribute the runtime library with their applications that add significant functionality. That would presumably apply to the people who used to Visual C++ to build the wxPython package you're using, but that wouldn't necessarily transfer to you and your package. You might just want to point your users to the web page where they can download it directly from Microsoft directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short answer

What Visual C++ runtime your users needs depends on what version of Python you're using with `py2exe`.

- If you're using Python 2.6, Python 2.7, Python 3.0, Python 3.1, or Python 3.2: your users will need Visual C++ 2008 runtime installed
- If you're using Python 3.3 or Python 3.4: your users will need Visual C++ 2010 runtime installed
- If you're using Python 3.5 (or newer): your users will need Visual C++ 2015

### Long Answer

The reason why your end users need to have Visual C++ 2008 installed on their machine is because you're converting your application to a standalone executable.

When you run `py2exe` to create a standalone application, it creates a package that bundles `python27.dll` (or whatever, depending on what version of Python you were running when building the package). This is the library that allows you to have a standalone program, because it is used to run all the Python bytecode that `py2exe` bundles with your application.

That `python?.dll` library needs Visual C++ 2008's runtime libraries installed because almost every version of Python 2.x and Python 3.x for Windows machines has been compiled using Visual C++ 2008.

Additionally, you are using `wxPython`, which is a wrapper around the C++ library `wxWidgets`. `wxWidgets` is built using Visual C++ 2008 so you also need the runtime to use it.